Logistic regression by high level tensorflow keras API : wrong result
First implemented logistic regression using tensorflow keras low-level api. Then using high-level keras API implemented the same algorithm but loss/cost and accuracies are different. Low-level answer is correct as it matches logistic regression by scratch of deeplearning.ai. Google colab links of files is attached.
Below is low-level api logistic regression code which is giving correct output:
## initialize part
print_cost=True
num_epochs = 10
learning_rate = 0.005

w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(X.shape[0],1))) # shape=(2,1)
b = tf.Variable(0.0)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate)
accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()

## training part
for i in range(num_epochs):

    # forward pass
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        z = tf.add(tf.matmul(tf.transpose(w), X), b)
        bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy( from_logits=True, label_smoothing=0.0, axis=-1, reduction='sum', name='binary_crossentropy')
        cost = bce(Y, z)
    # backward pass
    trainable_variables = [w, b]
    grads = tape.gradient(cost, trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, trainable_variables))

    # Print the cost every 100 training epochs
    if print_cost:
        accuracy.update_state(Y, tf.sigmoid(z))
        print(f"Epoch {i+1}/{num_epochs}  -  Cost:{cost.numpy()}  -  Accuracy:{accuracy.result().numpy()}")
        accuracy.reset_states()


Epoch 1/10  -  Cost:0.6931471824645996  -  Accuracy:0.6555023789405823
 Epoch 2/10  -  Cost:0.7410295009613037  -Accuracy:0.6555023789405823
Epoch 3/10  -  Cost:0.7531536817550659  -  Accuracy:0.3444976210594177
Epoch 4/10  -  Cost:0.8667086958885193  -  Accuracy:0.6555023789405823
Epoch 5/10  -  Cost:0.768563449382782  -  Accuracy:0.34928229451179504
Epoch 6/10  -  Cost:0.897014319896698  -  Accuracy:0.6555023789405823
Epoch 7/10  -  Cost:0.7556132674217224  -  Accuracy:0.3684210479259491
Epoch 8/10  -  Cost:0.8804366588592529  -  Accuracy:0.6555023789405823
Epoch 9/10  -  Cost:0.7514852285385132  -  Accuracy:0.4019138813018799
Epoch 10/10  -  Cost:0.8771329522132874  -  Accuracy:0.6555023789405823

Below is high-level api logistic regression code which is giving incorrect output:
# Create the model
model = k.models.Sequential()
model.add( k.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(X.shape[0],),     #X.shape[0]=2
                          kernel_initializer=k.initializers.Zeros(), bias_initializer=k.initializers.Zeros()) )

# Compile the model
model.compile(
    optimizer=k.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.005),
    loss=k.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
    metrics=[k.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()],
)

# Train the model
model.fit(tf.transpose(X), tf.transpose(Y), epochs=10, shuffle=False, batch_size=1)


Epoch 1/10 209/209 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step -
loss: 2.6512 - binary_accuracy: 0.5550 Epoch 2/10 209/209
[==============================] - 1s 4ms/step - loss: 2.0159 -
binary_accuracy: 0.6459 Epoch 3/10 209/209
[==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 1.6735 -
binary_accuracy: 0.6651 Epoch 4/10 209/209
[==============================] - 1s 4ms/step - loss: 1.4703 -
binary_accuracy: 0.6842 Epoch 5/10 209/209
[==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 1.2202 -
binary_accuracy: 0.7129 Epoch 6/10 209/209
[==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 1.0095 -
binary_accuracy: 0.7464 Epoch 7/10 209/209
[==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 0.9206 -
binary_accuracy: 0.7368 Epoch 8/10 209/209
[==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 0.7307 -
binary_accuracy: 0.7703 Epoch 9/10 209/209
[==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.7977 -
binary_accuracy: 0.7799 Epoch 10/10 209/209
[==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.5660 -
binary_accuracy: 0.7943

Unable to correctly implement logistic regression in keras high-level api tensorflow but has successfully implemented in low-level api. Kindly correct my logic in last code snippet.

You cannot initialize weights to zeros, this is covered in a basic ML course. You also have switched what conceptually high and low level APIs are.

Yes, initializing weights to zero is bad(reason: weights on neurons are same so they all act as one neuron and also local minima problem) but here intentionally, writing code of simple "single" neuron without optimization techniques.
Regarding switching APIs, have mentioned second code part(containing model layers, fit, compile) is high-level.
My concern is that how is high-level code giving different results(loss and accuracy) than low-level code as according to my knowledge, both have same optimizer, accuracy, loss and weight initialization.
Thanks for your time.

They don't, there are differences, one is the use of from_logits=True.

in low-api, "from_logits=True" because can directly feed z(=wx+b) in tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy. While in high-API, we define layer of 1 unit with sigmoid activation. So, there was no way but to feed sigmoid in tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(so here "from_logit=False" by default). It is less flexible as high-level api. But both are doing same thing.

No, you should implement the exact same algorithm, no modifications.

@Dr.Snoopy Deleting activation sigmoid from layer and adding "from_logit=True" made no difference. See detail below:

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Lower-level API code is whole batch logistic regression while high-level API code is stochastic logistic regression as batch_size=1. Changing batch_size=number_of_sample which in my case is X.shape[1]; makes high-level API also whole batch logistic regression and thus, gives same output as lower-level one.
# Create the model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add( tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(X.shape[0],), 
                          kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros(),  bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Zeros()) )

# Compile the model
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.005),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()],
)

# Train the model
model.fit(tf.transpose(X), tf.transpose(Y), epochs=10, shuffle=False, batch_size=X.shape[1])


Epoch 1/10 1/1 [==============================] - 1s 972ms/step -
loss: 0.6931 - binary_accuracy: 0.6555 Epoch 2/10 1/1
[==============================] - 0s 40ms/step - loss: 0.7410 -
binary_accuracy: 0.6555 Epoch 3/10 1/1
[==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 0.7532 -
binary_accuracy: 0.3445 Epoch 4/10 1/1
[==============================] - 0s 34ms/step - loss: 0.8667 -
binary_accuracy: 0.6555 Epoch 5/10 1/1
[==============================] - 0s 45ms/step - loss: 0.7686 -
binary_accuracy: 0.3493 Epoch 6/10 1/1
[==============================] - 0s 34ms/step - loss: 0.8970 -
binary_accuracy: 0.6555 Epoch 7/10 1/1
[==============================] - 0s 37ms/step - loss: 0.7556 -
binary_accuracy: 0.3684 Epoch 8/10 1/1
[==============================] - 0s 28ms/step - loss: 0.8804 -
binary_accuracy: 0.6555 Epoch 9/10 1/1
[==============================] - 0s 29ms/step - loss: 0.7515 -
binary_accuracy: 0.4019 Epoch 10/10 1/1
[==============================] - 0s 34ms/step - loss: 0.8771 -
binary_accuracy: 0.6555

